# How to use the result I retrieved from REST api in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, json, rest, ionic-framework

I am currently working on using RESTful service to retrieve data from my db. I have managed to successfully read data from db, however, I am unable to make use of the data I have retrieved. Mainly because I do not know how to store the json into a variable.

These are my codes below

Variable I have declared to store the result

`users: any;`

Method to retrieve from rest api

```
getUser(username:string, pw:string){
    this.restProvider.getUsers(username, pw)
      .subscribe(userList => {console.log(userList);

        this.users = userList.result},

        () => { console.log(this.users); });
  }
```

Method to use the result

```
pressLogIn(event){

    this.getUser(this.username, this.pw);

    console.log(users)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**login.html**

```
<form (submit)="getUser()" [formGroup]="loginForm">

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>
      <ion-icon name="person" color="primary"></ion-icon>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" placeholder="System ID" formControlName="username"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>
      <ion-icon name="lock" color="primary"></ion-icon>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="pw"></ion-input>

  </ion-item>

  <p color="danger" ion-text *ngIf="loginError">{{loginError}}</p>

  <button type="submit" ion-button mode="ios" block [disabled]="loginForm.invalid">Login</button>
</form>
```

**login.ts**

```
public getUser() {
this.loading = this.loadingController.create({ content: 'Please Wait...' });
this.loading.present();
this.loginError = '';
this.restProvider.getUser(
  this.loginForm.get('username').value,
  this.loginForm.get('pw').value).subscribe((userList: any) => {
    this.users = userList.result
    this.loading.dismiss();
  }, err => {
    this.loginError = "Something went wrong, please try again";
    this.loading.dismiss();
  }, () => {
console.log(this.users);
  })


}
```

**NOTE: I have used reactive forms if you have used a template driven form then modify accordingly**

Comment: Sorry... but this doesn't seems to be answering to my question. I am not using a form and also, I am trying to not put my validation inside the getUser method. Hence, the two separate methods.

Comment: if you are not using a form, then simply pass username and password to `getUser()` method like  `public getUser(){this.restProvider.getUser(this.username, this.pw).....}`

Comment: You have modified your question, my answer seems completely irrelevant.